# Is it a bad thing to give more than one example in a [big-list] question?

Tags: discussion, policy

In most [big-list] questions, I see that every person has entered at most one example. Why is this so?

I recently provided about 5 examples in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2140493/counter-intuitive-examples-in-probability/) answer. Is that considered a bad thing?